# Why ajax call not returning success or error though controller sends data?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an Ajax call of 'GET' type which is hitting the mvc controller action properly. The controller action type is 'JsonResult' and it is returning json data which should indicate success for the ajax call. But the ajax call is not responding for success or error.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + '/Controller_Name/Action_Name',
    type: 'GET',
    data: param,
    success: function (data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        if (response.length > 0 && response != '-1') {

            toastr.options.timeOut = 2500;
            toastr.success('Data retrieved successfully', 'Success');

        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {

        toastr.options.timeOut = 2500;
        toastr.warning('Error while retrieving data', 'Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is anything logged to the browser console?

Comment: please, use postam (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) and send us a result of a request.

Comment: I removed the JSON.Parse() method and it is working. The controller return type is JsonResult and I was using JSON.Parse() method on that returned json data. That's why it wasn't working. Now it's okay. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The controller action type is 'JsonResult' and it is returning json data which should indicate success for the ajax call

When we return `JSONResult` we get json object in the callback, so we don't need to Parse it. If the action returns like following:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

then in success the following should work:

```
success: function (data) {
           alert(data.success);
           if(data.success === true) {
                // do something here
           }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was really a silly mistake. I removed the JSON.Parse()  method and it is working.